# attendance table log mysql

Tags: mysql, date-range

I have an attendance table like this:

| Employee | Date_Time | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| std001 | 2024-02-01 22:01:00 | IN |
| std001 | 2024-02-02 06:00:05 | OUT |
| std001 | 2024-02-03 07:59:00 | IN |
| std001 | 2024-02-03 17:00:00 | OUT |
| std001 | 2024-02-04 06:00:00 | IN |
| std001 | 2024-02-04 14:00:00 | OUT |

I want to select from the table above with date range (ex. 2024-02-01 to 2024-02-05 to get result like this below:

| Employee | Date | DateTime_In | DateTime_Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| std001 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-01 22:01:00 | 2024-02-02 06:00:05 |
| std001 | 2024-02-02 | NULL | 2024-02-02 06:00:05 |
| std001 | 2024-02-03 | 2024-02-03 07:59:00 | 2024-02-03 17:00:00 |
| std001 | 2024-02-04 | 2024-02-04 06:00:00 | 2024-02-04 14:00:00 |
| std001 | 2024-02-05 | NULL | NULL |

The "DateTime_In" is from the "Date_Time" with status "IN", and if the "DateTime_In" is < 22:00:00 then the "DateTime_Out" is the "Date_Time" with status "OUT" from same date. But if the "DateTime_In" >= 22:00:00 then the "DateTime_Out" is the "Date_Time" with Status "OUT" from the next day. but if there are no "DateTime_In" and "DateTime_Out" then it show null on corresponding date.

Can anyone help me with the query in mysql server?

Row

```
std001  2024-02-02  NULL    2024-02-02 06:00:05 seems can be 
std001  2024-02-02  NULL    NULL . 
And/Or std001   2024-02-01  2024-02-01 22:01:00 2024-02-02 06:00:05 
--> std001  2024-02-02  2024-02-01 22:01:00 2024-02-02 06:00:05
```

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. provide output which completely matches shown data. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3

Comment: without an ordering column with unique values, this task will be impossible

Comment: @nbk Formally `Date_Time` column with uniqueness condition may be such ordering expression, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

The Date for the fifth makes no sense as it is not in the Table.

The Query can be improved to check if the LAG(`status`) is IN if two OUT can happen, but then the logic would be even more complicated

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  `Employee` VARCHAR(6),
  `Date_Time` DATETIME,
  `Status` VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO tab
  (`Employee`, `Date_Time`, `Status`)
VALUES
  ('std001', '2024-02-01 22:01:00', 'IN'),
  ('std001', '2024-02-02 06:00:05', 'OUT'),
  ('std001', '2024-02-03 07:59:00', 'IN'),
  ('std001', '2024-02-03 17:00:00', 'OUT'),
  ('std001', '2024-02-04 06:00:00', 'IN'),
  ('std001', '2024-02-04 14:00:00', 'OUT');
```

> ```
> Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
  `Employee`,
  DATE(`Date_Time`) `date`,
CASE WHEN `Status` = 'IN'  THEN `Date_Time` END `DateTime_In`,
CASE WHEN LEAD(`Status`) OVER (PARTITION BY `Employee` ORDER BY `Date_Time` ) = 'OUT'  
  THEN LEAD(`Date_Time`) OVER (PARTITION BY `Employee` ORDER BY `Date_Time` ) 
  ELSE 
  CASE WHEN DATE(LAG(`Date_Time`) OVER (PARTITION BY `Employee` ORDER BY `Date_Time` )) =  DATE(`Date_Time`)
     THEN NULL ELSE `Date_Time` END 
  END 'DateTime_Out'
FROM tab)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE `DateTime_Out` IS NOT NULL
```

| Employee | date | DateTime_In | DateTime_Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| std001 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-01 22:01:00 | 2024-02-02 06:00:05 |
| std001 | 2024-02-02 | *null* | 2024-02-02 06:00:05 |
| std001 | 2024-02-03 | 2024-02-03 07:59:00 | 2024-02-03 17:00:00 |
| std001 | 2024-02-04 | 2024-02-04 06:00:00 | 2024-02-04 14:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DM5HsuWH)